# I do not receive bounces

Tags: civimail, joomla, bounce

CiviCRM 4.6.4 With Joomla.
I mass mail are successfully sent. But I do not receive neither bounces nor notification of bounces. Some wrong or non existent mail addresses are used as a test.
Here following my settings:

[image: mailer setting]
[image: mailer setting cont.ed]

The mail server of my provider is able to manage bounces.
Could you help me to configure both the mail server and /or CiviCRM? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is some explanation here that you have probably already read http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/advanced-configuration/email-system-configuration/

Note it says: "The local part is optional and only relevant if you were able to set up an account using sub-addressing. It should be the account you created with '+' or '-' appended , e.g., "return+" or "return-"."

I see you have 'bounce' in that field which may be your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use IMAP as the protocol.

In addition to the doc petednz points to you might also find some useful info here.
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Step-by-step+Return+Channel+on+Drupal+-+Google+Apps+-+CentOS

This refers to using google apps but I think most of this applies to others.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from @petednz, you should check whether your email server at heldercamara.it supports plus-addressing in the first place.  Assuming you edit the local part to `bounces+`, you should send an email to bounces+lotsofgibberish@heldercamara.it and then log into bounces@heldercamara.it and see if it arrived.

If plus-addressing doesn't work on your server, you may be able to set a "default address" such that bounces@heldercamara.it receives all email to addresses on that server that don't exist.  Each bounce will go to something like b.14235.132342323@heldercamara.it (or bounces+b.14235.132342323@heldercamara.it with plus-addressing), so you need to scoop them all up and get them into a single mailbox.